# accessing variables in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

```
    var form_data = {
        username: $("#username").val(),
        password: $("#password").val(),
        is_ajax: 1
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(response) {
            if (response==username) {
```

I want to access username variable that i have declared in form_data variable. How can i?
i am using $("#username").val() but i want to access the variable.

Comment: `response==form_data.username`

Comment: How about `form_data.username` ?

Comment: please answer your solution, not comment. thank you

Comment: the solution is not worthy of an answer really. an answer could be an essay of how to access object properties in javascript or similar

Comment: its an answer regardless of whether its worth or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var form_data = {
        username: $("#username").val(),
        password: $("#password").val(),
        is_ajax: 1
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(response) {
            if (response==form_data.username) {
```

Comment: this appears to be simply a copy/paste of the jQuery from the OP

Comment: @KaeVerens: look at the last line

Comment: It's worth mentioning to the OP that this comparison will only work if "response" (what the server returns) is only the username as a string. You might want to structure your response to accomodate future information as well, even if the username is all you care about at this moment.

Comment: Agree with @GregPettit . When the dataType of the ajax request is text, I usually trim the response. like this: 
if( $.trim(response)==form_data.username)

Because response often comes with blank spaces at the beginning and at the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

`form_data.username` is the variable you want

```
if (response == form_data.username) {
```

so in result, it will all look like

```
var form_data = {
    username: $("#username").val(),
    password: $("#password").val(),
    is_ajax: 1
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: action,
    data: form_data,
    success: function(response) {
        if (response == form_data.username) {
```